# Extracting longtitude and latitude for plotly interactive map

Tags: python, plotly, data-science, geojson

I searched for videos on youtube concerning working with latitude and longtitude for creating
interactive map.
I have a dataset on earthquakes,where the longtitude and latitude are both float:
[Significant_Earthquakes_1900_2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORxaM.jpg)
I tried to use this code unsuccessfully:

```
import csv
filename = '/kaggle/input/significant-earthquake-dataset-1900-2023/Significant Earthquake Dataset 1900-2023.csv'
keys = ('Latitude','Longitude')
records = []
with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        records.append({keys:row[key] for key
                       in keys})
records[0]
record = records[0]
coords = record['Latitude','Longitude'].split("(")[-1].split(")")[0]
coords

I got eventually this output:
{('Latitude', 'Longitude'): '132.0763'}
132.0763
```

How can I create visualization for plotly using geojson,csv or folium?
Thanks

Comment: The data in the question is in csv file format, but it can be read with `pd.read_csv()` in pandas, why not use that? I'm guessing, but see the reference for an [example](https://plotly.com/python/bubble-maps/) of what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Look if the following code solves your issue:

```
import csv
filename = 'Significant Earthquake Dataset 1900-2023.csv'
keys = ('Latitude','Longitude')
records = []
with open(filename,'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        records.append({key: row[key] for key in keys})
records
```

The output:
[image]

I downloaded the file from kagle. I put the encoding because it resulted error. And instead of keys inside the loop, I replaced by key.

Answer (score 0):

you are storing the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' keys as a tuple instead of separate key-value pairs. Additionally, you are only processing the first record in the dataset.

```
import csv

filename = '/kaggle/input/significant-earthquake-dataset-1900-2023/Significant Earthquake Dataset 1900-2023.csv'
records = []

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        lat = float(row['Latitude'].split('(')[-1].split(')')[0])
        lon = float(row['Longitude'].split('(')[-1].split(')')[0])
        records.append({'Latitude': lat, 'Longitude': lon})

print(records[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem by casting longitude and latitude into a list                          
lats = list(df['Latitude'])
lons = list(df['Longitude'])
mag = list(df['Mag'])                                                                                                                           however, I couldn't  create a map plot since there was an error in installing cartopy.

Comment: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7efd23c8d160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/cartopy/